# Losing object reference when accessing data from different thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I apologize to write the whole bunch of code, but couldn't find words to explain my issue.

**Issue:**
`GameHandler` creates object of GameData and passed `this` as `ITraceble`.
`GameData` object has a reference of `ITraceable` object. `GameTask` implementes `Runnable`, so its going to run on a different thread. But when i try to call `m_gameData.traceMeNow()` from anywhere inside of `GameTask`, I am getting `m_game.m_traceable` as null.

```
public interface ITraceable {
     public void trace(String a_args);
}

public class GameData {
     ITraceable m_traceable;
     public GameData(ITraceable a_traceable) {
         m_traceable = a_traceable;
     }

     public void traceMeNow() {
         m_traceable.trace("something to trace");    <----- m_traceable ref is NULL.
     }
}

public class GameTask implements Runnable {
    GameData m_gameData;
    public GameTask(GameData a_gameData) {
        m_gameData = a_gameData;
        m_gameData.traceMeNow();                <---Function call from here
    }

    public void run() {
       //something here
    }
}

class GameHandler implements ITraceable {
    public void trace(String a_args) {
         //writting some logs here.
     }

    public void createObjects() {               < ------ Creating objects here
        GameData l_gameData = new GameData(this);
        GameTask l_gameTask = new GameTask(l_gameData);
        //--- Starting GameTask in other Thread ----// 
    }    
}
```

Comment: When and how is **l_gameTask** initiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable final:

```
final ITraceable m_traceable;
```

This guarantees that all threads will see the assigned value (provided the reference to `this` isn't unsafely published in the constructor, which it is not here).

Comment: I cant declare as final as i need to assign value from constructor.

Comment: @MicroEyes assigning in the constructor does not preclude making it final.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Actually i was assigning 'final ITraceable 
 m_traceable=null' in class itself and again in constructor and that was giving me error.